# Find a HWND that corresponds to the PID

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `int` called `pid`. I want to call a function using a `hwnd` of any window that is coming from this process. I have pieced together this code from pinvoke:

```
called(int pid)
{
    callBackPtr = new CallBackPtr(EnumReport.Report); <-- Does not work
    EnumReport.EnumWindows(callBackPtr, (IntPtr)pid);
}

public delegate bool CallBackPtr(int hwnd, int lParam);
private CallBackPtr callBackPtr;

public class EnumReport
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EnumWindows(CallBackPtr callPtr, IntPtr lPar);

    public bool Report(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        IntPtr lpdwProcessId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out lpdwProcessId);
        if (lpdwProcessId == lParam)
        {
            doThing(lParam);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This code does not work yet though. In the one line, it tells me that no Overload of Report matches Delegate CallBackPtr. What is the right way to fix this? I took the code from [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumWindows)

Comment: The sample seems wrong because the native function definition for EnumWindow's callback takes a a `HWND` and a `LPARAM`, both of which are marshalled to `IntPtr`, so it's wrong to use `int`s there. Who knows what other errors are in there.

Comment: int != IntPtr, fix the delegate declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that looks like (YMMV, very old code):

```
public class UnmanagedCode
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsDelegate CallBack, 
      ProcessWatcher processWatcher);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    internal static extern bool IsWindowVisible(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
    public static extern void GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder sb, int maxCount);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
    public static extern void GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder sb, int maxCount);

    public static bool EnumWindowsCallBack(int Hwnd, ProcessWatcher processWatcher)
    {
        if (!IsWindowVisible(Hwnd))
            return true;

        if (IsAltTabWindow(Hwnd))
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder windowClass = new StringBuilder(256);
                UnmanagedCode.GetClassName(Hwnd, windowClass, windowClass.Capacity);

                StringBuilder windowText = new StringBuilder(256);
                UnmanagedCode.GetWindowText(Hwnd, windowText, windowText.Capacity);

                IntPtr pid = (IntPtr)0;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(Hwnd, ref pid);

                processWatcher.Add(pid.ToInt32(), 
                  Hwnd, 
                  windowClass.ToString(), 
                  windowText.ToString());
            }
            catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    internal static bool IsAltTabWindow(int hwnd)
    {
        // Start at the root owner
        int hwndWalk = GetAncestor(hwnd, 3);

        // See if we are the last active visible popup
        int hwndTry;
        while ((hwndTry = GetLastActivePopup(hwndWalk)) != hwndTry)
        {
            if (IsWindowVisible(hwndTry)) break;
            hwndWalk = hwndTry;
        }
        return hwndWalk == hwnd;
    }


}

public class ProcessWatcher
{
  private List<MyProcess> _processes = new List<MyProcess>;

  public UnmanagedCode.EnumWindowsDelegate callback 
    = new UnmanagedCode.EnumWindowsDelegate(UnmanagedCode.EnumWindowsCallBack);

  public void Update()
  {
    foreach (var proc in _processes )
    {
      proc.Updated = false;
    }

    UnmanagedCode.EnumWindows(callback, this);

    _processes = _processes
      .Where(p => p.Updated)
      .ToList();
  }

  public void Add(int processID, 
    int windowHandle, 
    string className, 
    string windowText)
  {

    var currentProcess = _processes.FirstOdDefault(p => p.ProcessId = processId);

    if (currentProcess != null)
    {
      // still running, already found
      currentProcess.Updated = true;
    }
    else // new process
    {
      try
      {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId)
        fileName = proc.MainModule.ModuleName;
        _processes.Add(new MyProcess
          {
            ProcessId = processId,
            WindowHandle = windowHandle,
            ClassName = className,
            WindowText = windowText,
            FileName = fileName
          });
      }
      catch {}
    }
}
```

Comment: As Etienne's comment points out, these p/invoke declarations are using the wrong type, which will cause problems on x64

Answer (score 0):

Something similar, using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation?view=netframework-4.7.2).

The **`UIAFindWindows`** recursive method returns all the top level Windows of a specified `Process ID` and all its Child Windows using a custom class as container for the data.

The method can be called like this:

```
List<ElementWindows> WindowHandles = UIAFindWindows(ProcessID, null);
```

Passing `null` as parameter causes the search to start from the Desktop as the [AutomationElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) ancestor, corresponding to the [AutomationElement.RootElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.rootelement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.RootElement);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2).

The [AutomationElement.FindAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FindAll);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) method is used to collect all the child Elements in the Scope ([TreeScope.Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.treescope?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2)).

This method requires a project reference to `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes`

```
using System.Windows.Automation;

public class ElementWindows
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public IntPtr MainWindowHandle { get; set; }
    public string MainWindowTitle { get; set; }
    public List<ElementWindows> SubWindows { get; set; }
}

public static List<ElementWindows> UIAFindWindows(int ProcessId, AutomationElement Root)
{
    if (Root == null) Root = AutomationElement.RootElement;
    List <ElementWindows> results = new List<ElementWindows>();
    var MatchingWindows = Root.FindAll(
        TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));

    foreach (AutomationElement Window in MatchingWindows)
    {
        object ElementProcessId = Window.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, true);
        if (ElementProcessId != AutomationElement.NotSupported && ProcessId == (int)ElementProcessId)
        {
            ElementWindows foundElement = new ElementWindows()
            {
                ProcessId = ProcessId,
                MainWindowHandle = (IntPtr)Window.Current.NativeWindowHandle,
                MainWindowTitle = Window.Current.Name,
                SubWindows = UIAFindWindows(ProcessId, Window)
            };
            results.Add(foundElement);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```